# nginx-ingress - eks 400 bad request

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, ingress-nginx

I've got an AWS EKS environment that i'm just setting up and I'm getting 400 bad request.

Below is my config and I wanted to ask if anyone saw anything I should change.

I can see the requests are getting through the aws NLB as it reaches the nginx ingress controller but I can't see any decent information in the ingress controller logs. will add some below.

I'm terminating 443 at the NLB so sending http/80 to controller...

```
W0408 01:06:35.428413       7 controller.go:1094] Service "dating/photoapi-prod" does not have any active Endpoint.
W0408 01:06:35.428682       7 controller.go:1094] Service "dating/photoapi-test" does not have any active Endpoint.
192.168.119.209 - - [08/Apr/2022:01:50:55 +0000] "\x00" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.000 [] [] - - - - 1d65f0090db1addb14e870d877977bfc
192.168.119.209 - - [08/Apr/2022:01:50:59 +0000] "\x00" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.000 [] [] - - - - b853574052dfd56745839f72a6fc5ed1
192.168.90.222 - - [08/Apr/2022:01:50:59 +0000] "\x00" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.000 [] [] - - - - c38d59e8ffcb008cf01ab4bb3ea4cd39
192.168.90.222 - - [08/Apr/2022:01:51:00 +0000] "\x00" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.000 [] [] - - - - 3ca1bfdbb1f35c7b89d213636a12e864
192.168.119.209 - - [08/Apr/2022:01:51:05 +0000] "\x00" 400 150 "-" "-" 0 0.000 [] [] - - - - 338a2445058641d71c32e9acdf467118
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it fixed after remove unused listening port in LB.
I thinks it occured by health check.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As per error it says the service behind the ingress controller doesn’t have active container running behind it.

Do you have container running behind the services mentioned in error?